# Filtering the search using select dropdown

Tags: php, html

I wrote this code and it filters the search using the select dropdown. I have a search box, but my problem is: if i put something in the search box, it doesn't show anything even if I searched the data that is present in the database.

The dropdown is working but if I try to select the 3 options in those three select (ex Grade12, ICT, A), it will show me the record that has grade 12, and ICT but B in the section. I don't have any data that has A on it, so I want it to show nothing since the A is not present, but it shows data that has a different section (A is section btw)

```
<div class = "records">
    <table width ="600" border = "1" cellpadding ="1" cellspacing ="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Strand</th>
            <th>Section</th>
        </tr>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $box = $_POST['box'];
    $box = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$box);
    $grade =$_POST['grade'];
    $strand = $_POST['strand'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE grade ='$grade' or track ='$strand' or section = '$section' or fname ='%$box%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['mname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['grade']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['track']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['section']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }      
  }              
else {          
}

?>
```

then the front end

```
link rel = "stylesheet" href ="style.css">
<body>
  <form action ="../pages/section.php" method="POST" >
    <div class = "view">
      <input type = "text" name="box" placeholder = "search here">
      <label class = grade2></label>
      <select class = "grade" name = "grade">
        <option value ="" >=====Grade=====</option>
        <option value ="Grade11">Grade 11</option>
        <option value ="Grade12">Grade 12</option>
      </select>
      <select class = "strand" name = "strand">
         <option >=====Strand=====</option>
         <option value ="GAS">GAS</option>
         <option value ="ICT">ICT</option>
         <option value ="STEM">STEM</option>
         <option value ="HUMSS">HUMMSS</option>
         <option value ="ABM">ABM</option>
       </select>
       <select class = "section" name = "section">
         <option value ="1">=====Section=====</option>
         <option value ="A">A</option>
         <option value ="B">B</option>
         <option value ="C">C</option>
         <option value ="D">D</option>
         <option value ="E">E</option>
       </select> 
       <input type="submit" name="search" value= "Submit">
```

they're on the same file btw, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose `$box = "foo"`

When doing in your query `WHERE fname ='%$box%'`, it will **literally** search for the string `%foo%`.

If you want to use wildcards, you have to use `LIKE` operator instead of `=`. `WHERE fname LIKE '%$box%'` will search for a string **containing** `foo`

---

Beside that, your query is wide open to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

You are removing characters that aren't alpha numerics in `$_POST['box']` But this isn't enough. (and this is pretty bad, you can't search for `"Obi Wan"` or `"Obi-Wan"`, this will rather search for `"ObiWan"`)

Nothing stops a user to press <kbd>F12</kbd> and change the values in the dropdown to inject SQL code.

Comment: I'm new to php and yah I'm still learning about prepared statements, I did not put a prepared statement in my code because I'm still having trouble handling every statements in php after I'm done with the whole website, I think i'm going to put it as my finishing touches, well I'm willing to learn though, if you have any advice I'm happy to take it sir :) @Cid

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for "or"

```
or section = '$section'
```

Records that don't match $section will be shown.
If you don't want, you have to use a "and"

Comment: I tried this code `$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE fname LIKE '$box%' or mname LIKE '%$box%' or lname LIKE '%$box%' AND grade = '$strand' or section = '$section'"; but it doesnt work I dont know why

Comment: Have you found a solution, or do you us to take a look?

Comment: It's still the same, I haven't found a solution yet sir @dassoun

Comment: Can you give us the params you set to the request, and the records sent while they should not, according to you?

Comment: what params sir? I want the function to work like this, if I click on grade 12, A it will show all the grade 12 in section A, but it also shows the section B and C of grade 12

Comment: What about the other params?
When you execute your query in a sql client, and so, with exactly the same params, is the result of your php script different than in the sql client.
Do you know SQL?
Display your sql once params are filled, compare it to what you are waiting for. If it is what you are waiting for, execute THIS query in a sql client, and compare it to what you obtain with your php script.
You can try to give us the sql query generated by your script, I mean the real query, filled with the parameters